# WPF handle error/exception from app.config on app startup

Tags: wpf, xaml, app-config

I'm trying to capture error in the App.config file on application startup, but I'm not getting.
All global error events (as AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException or Application.DispatcherUnhandledException) are not working to catch the incorret format App.Config file, even as the OnStartup method App.xaml, is not being called, the application crashes before.

Sample invalid app.config:

```
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="XXXX" type="TesteAssembly.MainSpace, TesteAssembly" />
  </configSections>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>

</configuration>
```

However, I found that if the App.config file is malformed, to create an instance of the Application class an exception is thrown. Thus, the only solution I found was to remove the App.xaml, create a class with the main method and manually start an instance of Application (App.xaml base class).

example:

```
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Application p = new Application();

            p.StartupUri = new Uri("MainWindow.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

            p.Run();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }


    }
```

There is another solution to this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Try manually loading your config like this to diagnose the problem. Put this code at the start of Main(). It is most likely that the section type name is wrong:

```
var configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configMap.ExeConfigFilename = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + ".config";
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Comment: My app.config is changed by the customer in the production environment (deployment). The aim is handle the failure on load the file e avoid application crashes without knowing the reason. His solution is valid but does not prevent the use of the Main method, as in my solution. Researched elsewhere to see if there was something without using the main method, ie using the App.xaml but not found. However, thank you for your contribution.